# Scheme (Racket) Getting a random boolean with probably 0 < p < 1

Tags: scheme, racket

In Racket scheme, what is the best way to get a random boolean which is true with probability 0 <= p <= 1?

Comment: Just generate a random number using `(random)` and use `(> p r)` where `r` is the generated number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, where you make the probabilities explicit:

```
#lang racket
(require math)
(define d (discrete-dist '(#t #f) '(0.6 0.4)))
(sample d 10)
```

Sample output:

```
'(#f #t #t #t #t #f #t #f #f #t)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is, as noted in the comments:

(< (random) p)